# Assigning size of array entered by user to array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, runtime-error

Why I can't use this code when I want to assign the size of array entered by user to array?

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int array[n];
```

And is there another way of doing this instead of using this construction?

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int *array;
array = new int[n];
```

Comment: Arrays declared in the first manner require a known, fixed size at compile time. For the second, you can also use a vector

Comment: Try using `std::vector` instead of managing memory yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to O'Reilly "C++ In A Nutshell" (2003),

```
An array is specified with a constant size in square brackets
```

Since your variable n is not a constant, it can't be used to specify the size of the array.

The same paragraph also says,

```
For an array-like container whose size can change at runtime, see <vector> in Chapter 13.
```

Sorry, but you are not allowed to have this construction.